# How to make Drupal to login and send email via Gmail?

Tags: 9, emails

I have a Drupal 9 website with a core contact form (I don't use Webform).

I have two Gmail accounts, one by which I want to send email and one to which I should receive the email.

So I need a way to make Drupal log in to my *Gmail_account_1* and use it to send email (contact form inquiries) from it to my *Gmail_account_2*.

I think that in the Linux world this methodology is named *sSMTP*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [SMTP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp), but Gmail has some odd configuration and [you may run into issues, including having to manually log in to the Gmail account and check "allow insecure apps" every few weeks.](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp/issues/3227714)

So I would recommend not doing this and instead using a professional mail service like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) to send mail instead.